# How to group string of characters by 4?

Tags: regex, perl

I have string `1234567890` and I want to format it as `1234 5678 90`

I write this regex:

```
$str =~ s/(.{4})/$1 /g;
```

But for this case `12345678` this does not work. I get excess whitespace at the end:

```
>>1234 5678 <<
```

I try to rewrite regex with lookahead:

```
s/((?:.{4})?=.)/$1 /g;
```

**How to rewrite regex to fix that case?**

Comment: You can write `$str =~ s/.{4}\K(?!$))/ /g;` but you can also chomp the result.

Comment: The intro paragraph of your now deleted answer where you said "*I notice mistake while writing the question*" made it sound like you made a mistake when phrasing the question and that's why suggested you update your question instead. Looking at it now, I realize it was an attempt to point out the specific problem with `s/((?:.{4})?=.)/$1 /g;` ... Sorry.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use unpack to split a string into characters in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2677783/can-i-use-unpack-to-split-a-string-into-characters-in-perl)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use `unpack`

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

for ( qw/ 12345678 1234567890 / ) {
    printf ">>%s<<\n", join ' ', unpack '(A4)*';
}
```

#### output

```
>>1234 5678<<
>>1234 5678 90<<
```

Answer (score 6):

Context is your friend:

```
join(' ', $str =~ /(.{1,4})/g)
```

In list context, the match will all four character chunks (and anything shorter than that at the end of the string -- thanks to greediness). `join` will ensure the chunks are separated by spaces and there are no trailing spaces at the end.

If `$str` is huge and the temporary list increases the memory footprint too much, then you might just want to do the `s///g` and strip the trailing space.

My preference is for using the simplest possible patterns in regexes. Also, I haven't measured but with long strings, just a single `chop` might be cheaper than a conditional pattern in the `s///g`:

```
$ echo $'12345678\n123456789' | perl -lnE 's/(.{1,4})/$1 /g; chop; say ">>$_<<"'
>>1234 5678<<
>>1234 5678 9<<
```

Comment: This is interesting. Thanks

Comment: I use lookahead to prevent trailing space

Answer (score 4):

You had the syntax almost right.  Instead of just `?=.`, you need `(?=.)` (parens are part of the lookahead syntax).  So:

```
s/((?:.{4})(?=.))/$1 /g
```

But you don't need the non-capturing grouping:

```
s/(.{4}(?=.))/$1 /g
```

And I think it is more clear if the capture doesn't include the lookahead:

```
s/(.{4})(?=.)/$1 /g
```

And given your example data, a non-word-boundary assertion works too:

```
s/(.{4})\B/$1 /g
```

Or using \K to automatically Keep the matched part:

```
s/.{4}\B\K/ /g
```

Comment: strange, but my own answer where I use `s/(.{4}(?=.))/$1 /g` was deleted by moderator (

Comment: @EugenKonkov Sorry, my bad. It was flagged as "must be an edit to the post", I read the first sentence and it looked like a correction to the question and hence I deleted it. (used to seeing bad posts, about 2500 flags per day, so my eyes lied to me). Sorry again. :(

Answer (score 3):

To fix the regex I should write:

```
$str =~ s/(.{4}(?=.))/$1 /g;
```

I should just add parentheses around `?=.`. Without them `?=.` is counted as non greed match followed by `=.`

So we match four characters and append space after them. Then I look ahead that there are still characters. For example, the regex will not match for string `1234`

Answer (score 1):

Just use a look ahead to see that you have at least one character remaining:

```
$ echo $'12345678\n123456789' | perl -lnE 's/.{4}\K(?=.{1})/ /g; say ">>$_<<"'
>>1234 5678<<
>>1234 5678 9<<
```